# MySQL query: select the pages of the first generation only?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I want to select the children pages (**first generation**) that derived from parent pages but **not** the children pages (**second generation**, 3rd, etc) derived from the **first generation**, for instance,

```
pg_id     pg_title      parent_id
1         A             1            
2         B             2
3         C             1
4         d             1
5         e             1
6         f             4
7         g             4
8         k             5
9         l             3
10        j             3
```

So I want to get a result like this,

```
pg_id     pg_title      parent_id
3         C             1
4         d             1
5         e             1
```

The query below will select the **generations** branched from the `first generation`,

```
$sql = "
    SELECT *
    FROM root_pages
    WHERE root_pages.parent_id != root_pages.pg_id
    ORDER BY pg_created DESC
    ";
```

How can I get the **first generation** only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it, if I'm understanding your question right.

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM root_pages 
 WHERE parent_id IN (
     SELECT pg_id 
     FROM root_pages 
     WHERE parent_id = pg_id
 ) AND
 parent_id != pg_id
```

Answer (score 0):

For first generation only :

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM root_pages 
 WHERE parent_id = (
     SELECT pg_id 
     FROM root_pages 
     WHERE parent_id = pg_id order by pg_id asc limit 0, 1
 )
```

and ofcourse to remove self your logic can be added... ie. `parent_id <> pg_id`